# Write down linear system describing the flow in the network

Tags: linear-algebra, network-flow

[Network question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vmnW.png)

I currently have the following answer:

```
X1 - X2 - X3 - X4 = 0
X2 = 1
X3 = -1
X4 = 5
```

But the answer sheet says this is correct:

```
X1 = 1
X1 - X2 - X3 - X4 = 0
X2 = 1
X3 = 1
X4 = 3
```

Is the answer sheet wrong? Or am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking the picture I see:

$$ 1+x_2=2\rightarrow x_2=1\\
x_1=x_2+x_3+x_4\\
2+x_3+1=2 \rightarrow x_3=-1\\
x_4=4+1=5
$$

Comment: First of all, thanks for the quick respond. 
Exactly what I thought. I think the answer sheet is wrong once again..

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird: I think so!